# example code for Spark GraphX squaring the adjacency matrix

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, graph-theory, apache-spark

I have a bipartite graph that I would like to project onto 2 new graphs (e.g. using the network from the internet movie database of actors and movies, projecting out the actor network and the movie network with weights corresponding to number of movies (actors) in common)

In regular matrix notation, one simply needs to square the adjacency matrix and ignore the diagonal (which is equal to the original graph outdegree).  Presumably there are quicker edge-based algorithms for large sparse graphs, which is why I became interested in using Spark / GraphX with Hadoop and Map Reduce frameworks.

So, how do I do this A^2 calculation in Spark GraphX?

Say I begin with this code:

```
import org.apache.spark.graphx._ 
val orig_graph = GraphLoader.edgeListFile(sc, "bipartite_network.dat")
```

All of the functions I see are joins on vertices, joins on edges, or maps for vertex attributes or edge attributes.  How do I loop over all edges doubly and create a new graph with EDGES that are based on vertex ids?

Here's some pseudocode:

```
for i = 1 to orig_graph.edges.count 
   for j = i to orig_graph.edges.count 
      var edge1 = orig_graph.edges.[i] 
      var edge2 = orig_graph.edges.[j] 
      if edge1.1 == edge2.1 then add new edge = (edge1.2, edge2.2) 
      if edge1.1 == edge2.2 then add new edge = (edge1.2, edge2.1) 
      if edge1.2 == edge2.1 then add new edge = (edge1.1, edge2.2) 
      if edge1.2 == edge2.2 then add new edge = (edge1.1, edge2.1)
```

something like that.

Do I need to use Pregel and message passing, or just use the various graph.join functions?

See also http://apache-spark-developers-list.1001551.n3.nabble.com/GraphX-adjacency-matrix-example-td6579.html

Comment: Here's an algorithm based on http://adhoop.wordpress.com/2012/03/31/matrix-multiplication-using-mapreduce-1-step-solution/:  let's call the edge weight for link (i,j) = Aij = Bij.  I want to write a map function that emits {(i,j),('A',j,Aij)} AND emits {(j,k),('B',j,Bjk)}, and then a reduce function that for all (i,k) pairs sums Aij*Bjk over j = Pik and emits {(i,k),Pik}.  This will then be my new edge list and weights to output.

Forget for a second whether that algorithm works or not... my question is how do I write a .map and .reduce function in Scala using the graphx classes and execute?

Comment: Ok, I've solved it some more... calling this function passes through the list, but only returns ONE edge at the end.  Help!  Why aren't all of the edges returned?    orig_graph.edges.map(ED => Edge(ED.srcId, ED.dstId, ED.attr)).reduce( (A,B) => Edge(A.srcId, B.dstId, A.attr*B.attr) )